# How can I extend NavigationView back button into a custom titlebar in my UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui

Properly extend the NavigationView back button into the titlebar

What I would like to do is to have my navigation view control's back button to be next to the title bar grid, like it is in windows 11 settings or [Microsoft store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNbn6.png)

My code is

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="testuwpnavigation.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:testuwpnavigation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="App title" Margin="40,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
        </Border>
        <controls:NavigationView IsTabStop="False" IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1">
            <controls:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <controls:NavigationViewItem Content="Item1" Icon="Home"/>
                <controls:NavigationViewItem Content="Item1" Icon="Home"/>
                <controls:NavigationViewItem Content="Item1" Icon="Home"/>
                <controls:NavigationViewItem Content="Item1" Icon="Home"/>
            </controls:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </controls:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace testuwpnavigation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            var titleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
            titleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried setting the IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled to false but it is still not working. It ends up like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTgyO.png)

Comment: Is it UWP of WinUI3? they are not the same thing

Comment: @SimonMourier it is uwp, but i use the nuget package Microsoft.UI.Xaml

Comment: That's WinUI 2, not WinUI 3, they are different technologies.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about customizing title bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar effect by [customizing the title bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui2#interactive-content). Add a button in the upper left corner of the page, and call [Frame.GoBack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.goback?view=winrt-22621) in the button click event to implement the back function.

The following code is for your reference.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" />

    <Button x:Name="AppTitleButton"
    Content="⬅" 
    Background="Transparent"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"         
    Click="AppTitleButton_Click"/>

    <NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemInvoked="NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem  Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
            <NavigationViewItem  Icon="Keyboard" Content="Main Item"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

---

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Hide default title bar.
        CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar =
            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

        // Set XAML element as a drag region.
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
    }

    private void NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.InvokedItem.ToString() == "Home" )
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        }
    }

    private void AppTitleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            ContentFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```